# Hide table TR but keep TH displayed

Tags: html, css, html-table

html code:

```
<table class='cTable'><th>Title</th>
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item3</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS code:

```
.cTable tr {
    display: none;
}
```

This thing, not only hides the rows but also the head. Is there any way to avoid it?

**I would like NOT to place a `display: none;` on each tr element if possible**.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vT4r9/1/

I tried this:

html

```
<table class='cTable'><th class='cTableTH'>Title</th>
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item3</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.cTable tr {
    display: none;
}

.cTableTH {
    display: block;
}
```

but doesn't work either.

http://jsfiddle.net/vT4r9/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong. Change it this way:

#### HTML

```
<table class='cTable'>
<tr><th class='cTableTH'>Title</th></tr>
<tr><td>Item1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item3</td></tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
.cTable tr {
    display: none;
}

.cTable tr:first-child {
    display: table-row;
}
```

#### Explanation

Giving `<th>` directly inside `<table>` is wrong. Even if you give, it gets into `<tr>` and then it displays. Whatever you give to `<th>` inside the hidden `<tr>` doesn't work.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vT4r9/11/

Answer (score 1):

You should cover `th` with `tr` and change the css like

```
    .cTable tr td{ display: none; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vT4r9/15/)**

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3afirst-child)

### css :

```
  cTable tr:not(:first-child){
           display:none;
  }
```

#### HTML :

```
 <table class='cTable'><tr><th class='cTableTH'>Title</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Item1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Item2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Item3</td></tr>
 </table>
```

its seem to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/vT4r9/14/

Comment: Doesn't work on IE browsers... And yeah, please avoid using CSS 3 when it comes to Cross Browser things. :)

Comment: i agree!! your solution is correct for this. i just share another option. but its seem to worked this solutionx in IE 9. any ways thanks for sharing your knowledge. +1 from my side :)

Comment: Yes, it works in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 (I am not sure about that)... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the HTML that's not correct. The [correct way](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) to define a table is using `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. Try this:

```
<table class='cTable'>
  <thead>Title</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Item1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

with this CSS:

```
.cTable tbody tr {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
.cTable td {
  display: none;
}
```

Hiding the cells instead of the rows should be enough. Also, you should wrap the `th` in a `tr` as already pointed by others.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can to hide the columns like this:

```
<style>
 .cTable td {
    display: none;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: sorry,simone..i misunderstood the question.